# Constructing a submanifold from a submanifold and smooth map

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Given a smooth manifold $M$ and a submanifold $N$. Let $f:M\rightarrow M$ be a smooth map with a constant rank. How to prove that the set $\{m\in M; f(m)\in N\}$ is a submanifold of $M$?

Comment: Can you answer this in the case that $M=\Bbb R^n$ and $N=\{x_{k+1}=\dots=x_n=0\}\subset M$?

Comment: Let $U$ be a chart on $M$ then $M\cap U=F^{-1}(0)$ where $F=(x_{k+1},...x_n):N\rightarrow \mathbb R^k$ (isomorphism?). Since $F$ and $f$ have  constant  ranks then $\{m\in M;f(m)\in N\cap U\}=(F\circ f)^{-1}(0)$   ?? This defines a submanifold charts on $\{m\in M;f(m)\in N\}$. So it is a submanifold of $N$??

Comment: No, $N\cap U = F^{-1}(0)$, and $F:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^{n-k}$. You need to sort things out here. But, yes, $f(x) \in N \iff F(f(x))=0$. Now you have to figure out how to use the rank condition.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. Consider $f : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ given by $f(x,y,z) = (x,y,x^2 - y^2)$ and $N = \{ (x,y,0) \, | \, x,y \in \mathbb{R} \}$.

Comment: So maybe we need $f$ to be an isomorphism?

Comment: If the map is a diffeomorphism, the result is trivial...